# Unsure how to resolve a pending promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise, map-function

I'm looping through some data and fetching individual navigation items.

If I `console.log(navItems)` before the `return` in the `getNavItems` function, it logs everything I expect.

However, if I log `footerData` before my return inside `getFooterData`, I'm returned with an unresolved promise inside my items

```js
[
  { heading: 'Heading 1', items: Promise { <pending> } },
  { heading: 'Heading 2', items: Promise { <pending> } },
  { heading: 'Heading 3', items: Promise { <pending> } },
]
```

What I'm expecting is something more like:

```js
[
  { heading: 'Heading 1', items: [ {data: 1}, {data: 2}, {data: 3} ] },
]
```

```js
const getNavitems = async (navItemList) => {
  const navItemIds = navItemList.map(({ sys: { id } }) => id);

  const navItemData = await Promise.all(
    navItemIds.map((id) => client.getEntry(id))
  );

  const navItems = navItemData.map((item) => item.fields);

  return navItems;
};

const getFooterData = async () => {
  const footerDataCollection = await client.getEntry('abcxyz123');

  const footerData = Object.entries(footerDataCollection.fields.sections).map(
    (item) => {
      return {
        heading: item[1].fields.heading,
        items: (() => getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list))()
      };
    }
  );

  return footerData;
};
```

Any help would be great as I've been banging my head on this for hours now!

Comment: similar to how you collected an array of promises and waited for them to be done for `navItemData`, so too do you have to wait on the promises in items.

Comment: Have you tried `(await client).getEntry('abcxyz123');`? Or `(await (await client).json()).getEntry('abcxyz123');`

Comment: Could try `return await Promise.all(footerData);`

Comment: @KevinB Where do I need to do this, sorry!  I'm not 100% sure I follow!

Comment: @Rojo / Nick - No luck - Thank you though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What does your `navItems` resolved Object look like?

Comment: @StackSlave navItems is an array of objects that just has 2 strings.  `[ { a: 'hello', b: 'world' } ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that uses a loop. (`Array.prototype.map` is tricky with `await`)

I haven't tested this, since I have no way to do it.

```
const getNavitems = async (navItemList) => {
  const navItemIds = navItemList.map(({ sys: { id } }) => id);

  const navItemData = await Promise.all(
    navItemIds.map((id) => client.getEntry(id))
  );

  const navItems = navItemData.map((item) => item.fields);

  return navItems;
};

const getFooterData = async () => {
  const footerDataCollection = await client.getEntry('abcxyz123');

  const footerData = Object.entries(footerDataCollection.fields.sections);

  const items = await Promise.all(footerData.map(item => getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list)));

  for (let i = footerData.length; i--;) {
      footerData[i] = {
          heading: footerData[i][1].fields.heading,
          items: items[i]
      }
  }

  return footerData;
};
```

Comment: This should throw an error due to using `await` in a non-async function. Making the map callback async will require additional code to get the intended array from it.

Comment: I noticed that too so I rewrote it so that it uses a loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead `items: (() => getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list))()` try `items: await getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list)`. What the anonymous function exactly is for there?

```
const footerData = await Promise.all(Object.entries(footerDataCollection.fields.sections).map(
    async (item) => {
      return {
        heading: item[1].fields.heading,
        items: await getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list)
      };
    }
  ));
```

Comment: `getNavitems` is already `async`. OP just needs `items: ()=>getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list)`, but that seems to not be the issue.

Comment: Would using await inside of Array.prototype.map like this cause all of the promises to be resolved in sequence one after the next? Or is that optimized away by the compiler such that promises are resolved in parallel?

Comment: Will execute in sequence, but the map will not wait for result, so the result of the executed functions may be ready in different order (like in parallel). `Promise.all([...])` wait until all functions done.

Answer (score -1):

In `items: (() => getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list))()`, you need to insert another `await`.

```
items: (async () => await getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list))()
```

`getNavItems` is an async function. Therefore, you must use `await` to get the return value.

Comment: Same outcome  

I do also get an eslint warning here too! 

>Redundant use of `await` on a return value.  eslint (no-return-await)

Comment: @Nick Try `items: await getNavitems(item[1].fields.item_list)`?

Comment: .map isn't going to wait for your await